# Heroku push failing with Create-React-App

Tags: reactjs, heroku, npm, deployment, create-react-app

I'm trying to deploy my create-react-app using Heroku. When I do `git push heroku master`, the build fails. 
This is the error log:

```
-----> React.js (create-react-app) multi app detected
=====> Downloading Buildpack: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-multi.git
=====> Detected Framework: Multipack
=====> Downloading Buildpack: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs.git
=====> Detected Framework: Node.js

-----> Creating runtime environment

       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false

-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)

       Resolving node version 12.x...
       Downloading and installing node 12.16.3...
       Using default npm version: 6.14.4

-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)

       > nodemailer@6.4.6 postinstall /tmp/build_258ba2b79ac9e7091bc7dd79a031dd4f/node_modules/nodemailer
       > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

       === Nodemailer 6.4.6 ===

       Thank you for using Nodemailer for your email sending needs! While Nodemailer
       itself is mostly meant to be a SMTP client there are other related projects in
       the Nodemailer project as well.

       For example:
       > IMAP API (  https://imapapi.com  ) is a server application to easily access
       IMAP accounts via REST API
       > NodemailerApp (  https://nodemailer.com/app/  ) is a cross platform GUI app to
       debug emails


       > styled-components@4.2.0 postinstall /tmp/build_258ba2b79ac9e7091bc7dd79a031dd4f/node_modules/styled-components
       > node ./scripts/postinstall.js || exit 0

       Use styled-components at work? Consider supporting our development efforts at https://opencollective.com/styled-components
       added 1914 packages from 1179 contributors and audited 2053 packages in 49.627s

       1 package is looking for funding
         run `npm fund` for details

       found 56466 vulnerabilities (39341 low, 26 moderate, 17098 high, 1 critical)
         run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

-----> Build
       Running build

       > juliesong@0.1.0 build /tmp/build_258ba2b79ac9e7091bc7dd79a031dd4f
       > react-scripts build  

       Creating an optimized production build...
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `npm update`
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command `npm update caniuse-lite browserslist`
       Failed to compile.

       ./src/components/PageIntro.js
       Cannot find module: 'axios'. Make sure this package is installed.

       You can install this package by running: npm install axios.


npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! juliesong@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build  `
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the juliesong@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.6BFeR/_logs/2020-05-17T06_58_22_399Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed

       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys

       Some possible problems:

       - Node version not specified in package.json
         https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version

       - A module may be missing from 'dependencies' in package.json
         https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys#ensure-you-aren-t-relying-on-untracked-dependencies

       Love,
       Heroku

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile React.js (create-react-app) multi app.
 !     Push failed
```

Here's my package.json file, in case it helps:

```
{
  "name": "juliesong",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "https://www.juliesong.me",
  "dependencies": { 
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "nodemailer": "^6.4.6",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-preloaders": "^3.0.3",
    "react-responsive": "^6.1.2",
    "react-responsive-carousel": "^3.1.49",
    "react-responsive-simple": "^0.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.1",
    "react-router-hash-link": "^1.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "^3.0.0",
    "styled-components": "^4.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build  ",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 9009 -s public",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook -s public",
    "predeploy": "npm run build && cp build/index.html build/404.html",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.3",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^5.0.6",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^5.0.6",
    "@storybook/addons": "^5.0.6",
    "@storybook/react": "^5.0.6",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
    "gh-pages": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "description": "This project was bootstrapped with [Create React App](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app).",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/jiyoonee/Website-Portfolio.git"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/jiyoonee/Website-Portfolio/issues"
  }
}
```

I did try to work around with gh-pages but it didn't seem to work so I tried switching to Heroku. It's my first time using it so any help on this issue would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: try to write in ur command line npm install and then to deploy one more time

Comment: The error message is fairly clear, but hidden in a lot of other output so it can be hard to find. `Cannot find module: 'axios'. Make sure this package is installed.`. This means the 'axios' module is not listed in your dependencies list in the package.json file. If you run `npm install axios` it should be added automatically if you have a newer version of npm, if not run `npm install --save axios`.